# How do I get access to the Qiskit Slack Channel

Tags: slack, qiskit

I have been trying to join https://qiskit.slack.com but there seems to be no possible way.

It sends a verification code to my email, but no matter what verification code it sends me, it will not accept it.

Does someone need to send me an invitation. If so, this should be documented in obvious places.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, the QisKit documentation at

https://qiskit.org/documentation/getting_started.html

Menu -> Resources -> Slack support

had a bad URL... the correct one is

https://ibm.co/joinqiskitslack